# Does Chrome's Content Download measure decoding time as well?

Tags: javascript, http, compression, gzip, deflate

I am currently looking into the performance of downloading a compressed javascript file to my app.

I can look at the Network debugging tab to determine how long it took the download the file, something like this:
[Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnsWg.png)

What I want to know is whether that 'Content Download' duration includes decompressing the compressed javascript file (compressed via gzip).

If it doesn't, where might this decompression duration be included?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I think it does count the time of decompression; I was trying to compare with wget the JS file, the time cost is much lower than downloading time in Chrome.